# Conditional query search in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have following document in elastic search indices/cluster

```
[
  {id: 1, firstName: 'User', lastName: 'John', nickName: 'Smith'},
  {id: 2, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'John', nickName: 'Andrew'},
  {id: 3, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Zch', nickName: 'John'},
  {id: 4, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Mason', nickName: 'John'},
  {id: 5, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},
  //should not search this
  {id: 6, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Glow', nickName: 'NonSearchText'}

];
```

My search requirement which looks similar like contact search in mobile:

Relevant search should be first with nickName then lastName. If nickName is not present then it should search with respect to firstName with ASC sorting order

**Search Text: John**

Hence the query search result should be

```
[
  // search with nickName as higher relevance and then sorted it
  {id: 4, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Mason', nickName: 'John'},
  {id: 3, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Zch', nickName: 'John'},
  // search with lastName as second higher relevance and then sorted it
  {id: 2, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'John', nickName: 'Andrew'},
  {id: 1, firstName: 'User', lastName: 'John', nickName: 'Smith'},
  // search with firstName as nickName is null
  {id: 5, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},

  // and omitted one record

];
```

Query written:

```
{
    "sort" : [

        {"lastName.keyword": "asc"},
        {"nickName.keyword": "asc"}
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{

                "query_string": {
                    "query": "John*",
                    "analyze_wildcard": "true",
                    "fields": ["nickName^3", "lastName^2"]

                }
            }]
        }
    }


}
```

I am not able to cover following scenarios:

1. Conditional based search if nickName is present and even if firstName matches search text, it should not include that document in the search
2. Search by firstName if nickName is not present

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "john",
            "fields": [
              "nickName^3",
              "lastName^2"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "nickName"
                }
              }
            ],
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "firstName": "john"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "lastName.keyword": "asc"
    },
    {
      "nickName.keyword": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Result**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index73",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "MxvATnIB8mx5yKbJqLHv",
        "_score" : 2.6264062,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 4,
          "firstName" : "Test",
          "lastName" : "Mason",
          "nickName" : "John"
        },
        "sort" : [
          2.6264062,
          "Mason",
          "John"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index73",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "MhvATnIB8mx5yKbJmrG2",
        "_score" : 2.6264062,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 3,
          "firstName" : "Test",
          "lastName" : "Zch",
          "nickName" : "John"
        },
        "sort" : [
          2.6264062,
          "Zch",
          "John"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index73",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "MRvATnIB8mx5yKbJh7F7",
        "_score" : 2.059239,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2,
          "firstName" : "Test",
          "lastName" : "John",
          "nickName" : "Andrew"
        },
        "sort" : [
          2.059239,
          "John",
          "Andrew"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index73",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "MBvATnIB8mx5yKbJcbG1",
        "_score" : 2.059239,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "firstName" : "User",
          "lastName" : "John",
          "nickName" : "Smith"
        },
        "sort" : [
          2.059239,
          "John",
          "Smith"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index73",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "NBvATnIB8mx5yKbJubHP",
        "_score" : 1.0296195,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 5,
          "firstName" : "John",
          "lastName" : "Doe"
        },
        "sort" : [
          1.0296195,
          "Doe",
          null
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: suggestion, you should provide explanation to your answer, simply posting query and result wont help.